# Angular templateUrl and supporting external resources such as Web API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, single-page-application

Multi-Tenant Website - .Net Core 1 with Angular 2/4

I'm creating a multi tenant app and I essentially want to give each tenant the ability to alter certain forms. Each form will contain the same view model and properties it's more of a layout/style thing. I want to use angular and I've been trying to use the templateUrl property on a component to fetch the html from an API endpoint in the same site. The endpoint works if accessed directly but doesn't when referenced in the angular component.

```
@Component({
    selector:'home',
    templateUrl:'/api/app-template-loader/login-form'
})
export class HomeComponent {

}
```

Controller:

```
[Route("api/app-template-loader")]
public class AppTemplateLoaderController : Controller
{
    private AppTenant currentTenant;
    public AppTemplateLoaderController(IEnumerable<AppTenant> tenant)
    {
        this.currentTenant = tenant.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{templateName}")]
    public string Get(string templateName)
    {
        if (templateName == "home")
        {
            return $"<h1>{this.currentTenant.Name}</h1>";
        }

        return "<h1>No template</h1>";
    }
}
```

I've tried something very basic but I just can't seem to get it to work. Accessing '/api/app-template-loader/login-form' in the browser returns html but when accessing the component I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./ClientApp/app/components/home/home.component.ts
        Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './/api/app-template-loader/login-form' in '<local disk path omitted for privacy>\ClientApp\app\components\home'
         @ ./ClientApp/app/components/home/home.component.ts 18:18-66
         @ ./ClientApp/app/app.module.shared.ts
         @ ./ClientApp/app/app.module.client.ts
         @ ./ClientApp/boot-client.ts
         @ multi event-source-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=%2F__webpack_hmr ./ClientApp/boot-client.ts
```

I assume this must be possible but I'm struggling to find any examples online and on here with the same issue.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you figure it out? i have the same problem here

Comment: @JônatasZulske unfortunately not, I ended up using VueJS and creating components that are loaded from a database at runtime, works great for a purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, it's just a problem of path.
Did you tried with :

```
templateUrl:'api/app-template-loader/login-form'
```

And then what is login-form ? If it's a folder it'd bug, if it's a file, can you browse it, is it accessible from web ? (use a web browser to verify it's availability).

PS : If you try to get an external ressource (of your web site), keep in mind that the response could be blocked to prevent Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS).

Comment: I've added the controller to the question now, still no joy with or without the forward slash. The question has all the other answers to your question already - It's an action on a controller, yes it's accessible and works directly.